# Worker container failed to connect back to Spark driver

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I made the Dockerfile as :

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/scipy-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

USER root

# Spark dependencies
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.3.2
ENV SPARK_HADOOP_PROFILE 2.7
ENV SPARK_SRC_URL https://www.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-$SPARK_VERSION/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${SPARK_HADOOP_PROFILE}.tgz
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
ENV PATH $PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
     postgresql && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV JAVA_HOME  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/

ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin


RUN wget ${SPARK_SRC_URL}

RUN tar -xzf spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${SPARK_HADOOP_PROFILE}.tgz   

RUN mv spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${SPARK_HADOOP_PROFILE} /opt/spark 

RUN rm -f spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${SPARK_HADOOP_PROFILE}.tgz





USER $NB_UID
ENV POST_URL https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar
RUN wget ${POST_URL}
RUN mv postgresql-42.2.5.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars
# Install pyarrow
RUN conda install --quiet -y 'pyarrow' && \
    conda install pyspark==2.3.2 && \
    conda clean -tipsy && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR && \
    fix-permissions /home/$NB_USER

WORKDIR $SPARK_HOME
```

Then I ran the command to make the my_notebook image as :
docker build -t my_notebook .

Then I made three containers Master,Worker and Notebook as follows :

Master using docker-compose file :

```
master:
      image: my_notebook
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h master
      hostname: master
      environment:
        MASTER: spark://master:7077
        SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
        SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: 192.168.XXX.XXX
      expose:
        - 7001
        - 7002
        - 7003
        - 7004
        - 7005
        - 7077
        - 6066
      ports:
        - 4040:4040
        - 6066:6066
        - 7077:7077
        - 8080:8080
      volumes:
        - ./conf/master:/conf
        - ./data:/tmp/data
```

Worker using docker-compose file :

```
worker:
      image: my_notebook
      command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.XXX.XXX:7077
      hostname: worker
      environment:
        SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
        SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 4
        SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 4g
        SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
        SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
        SPARK_BLOCKMGR_PORT: 5003
        SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
      expose:
        - 7012
        - 7013
        - 7014
        - 7015
        - 8881
        - 5001
        - 5003
      ports:
        - 8081:8081
      volumes:
        - ./conf/worker:/conf
        - ./data:/tmp/data
```

Notebook using docker-compose file :

```
notebook:
  image: my_notebook
  command: jupyter notebook
  hostname: notebook
  environment:
    SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: 192.168.XXX.XXX
  expose:
    - 7012
    - 7013
    - 7014
    - 7015
    - 8881
    - 8888
  ports:
    - 8888:8888
```

First I started the Master container in one machine as :
"docker-compose up"
Then started Worker on the other machine "docker-compose up"
Then started notebook in some other machine "docker-compose up"

Spark cluster was setup. Spark UI was accessible. Workers were registered too in the cluster.Jupyter notebook also started successfully. But the problem being faced is that when I run the pyspark application through jupyter worker executors failed to connect back to spark driver. 
Error logs are :

```
Spark Executor Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java" "-cp" "/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=35147" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@notebook:35147" "--executor-id" "31" "--hostname" "172.17.0.3" "--cores" "2" "--app-id" "app-20190101134023-0001" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.17.0.3:8881"
========================================

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to notebook:35147
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: notebook
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a url like `notebook:35147` to work, containers have to be in the same network. In your case, you are launching containers on difference machines, so that network has to be an overlay network.

The best solution is to use `docker swarm` and `docker stack` instead of docker-compose, but for the sake of not encumbering you with new things, let's just stick to compose for now.

First create such a network

We need a little help from the swarm mode:

On one machine (manager) do `docker swarm init` and `docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable my-network`

On other machines, `docker swarm join`  with the token you got on the manager.

Then modify all your compose files to have this at the end

```
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

and add this for services in question

```
networks:
   my-network
```

Comment: Or am I supposed to create overlay network on different machines as well?

Comment: And where to add these lines ? In all docker-compose files? I have 3 separate docker-compose files

Comment: Sorry for asking again what are services in it "and add this for services in question

networks:
   my-network"

Comment: When I tried to connect worker with manager it gives me the following error message error response from daemon : rpc error : code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error : desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.XXX.XXX:2337 : connect: connection refused